# Unable to fetch the data from AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to fetch the data from AWS dynamodb in eclipse maven/java but shows the following error

```
Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: NU99FP2PJA0PELJ9R20R7LCHSNVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
Cannot retrieve items.
Requested resource not found (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: 3DFTIT8QENPPB5L2BCQLCQJF2JVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
```

I have tried the following code to add the region but still showing this error

```java
dynamoDB.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.ap-south-1));
```

My code:

```java
package DB;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;

import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.partitions.model.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Item;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;


public class Test {
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    static DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(new AmazonDynamoDBClient( 
                  new ProfileCredentialsProvider())); 
      // dynamoDB.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.ap-south-1));  
//     Region usWest2 = Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1);
//       dynamoDB.setRegion(usWest2);
   static String tblName = "ProductList";
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      createItems();
      retrieveItem();

   }
   private static void createItems() {
      Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tblName);
      try {
         Item item = new Item()
            .withPrimaryKey("ID", 303)
            .withString("Nomenclature", "Polymer Blaster 4000")
            .withStringSet( "Manufacturers",
            new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("XYZ Inc.", "LMNOP Inc.")))
            .withNumber("Price", 50000)
            .withBoolean("InProduction", true)
            .withString("Category", "Laser Cutter");
            table.putItem(item);

         item = new Item()
            .withPrimaryKey("ID", 313)
            .withString("Nomenclature", "Agitatatron 2000")
            .withStringSet( "Manufacturers",
            new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("XYZ Inc,", "CDE Inc.")))
            .withNumber("Price", 40000)
            .withBoolean("InProduction", true)
            .withString("Category", "Agitator");

         table.putItem(item);
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Cannot create items.");
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
   private static void retrieveItem() {
      Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(tblName);
      try {
         Item item = table.getItem("ID", 303, "ID, Nomenclature, Manufacturers", null);
         System.out.println("Displaying retrieved items...");
         System.out.println(item.toJSONPretty());
      } catch (Exception e) {
         System.err.println("Cannot retrieve items.");
         System.err.println(e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I have also created the Table name as Product List in DynamoDB (Manually)

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, therefore make sure that your table does exist in `ap-south-1` region.

Comment: Thank you for your response.
The table exists in ap-south-1 region.